# Capture solution events in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio plugin. I want to capture the event of opening a new solution. In order to achieve this, I implemented `IVsSolutionEvents` interface and registered it using `AdviseSolutionEvents()`. However, when I run test instance of VS and open a solution, the proper event method is not being called.

Here is my code:

```
public sealed class MyPackage : Package, IVsSolutionEvents
{
        // ...

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();

            IVsSolution solution = GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
            uint cookie = 0;
            solution.AdviseSolutionEvents(this, out cookie);
        }

        // ...  

        public int OnAfterOpenSolution(object pUnkReserved, int fNewSolution)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Opened a solution!");
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }
}
```

Why is `OnAfterOpenSolution()` never called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

It turns out that  by default, Visual Studio packages are not loaded at startup, to avoid consuming memory and CPU. Instead, Visual Studio loads them when needed. Because of this, events are not registered before.

To change this behaviour one have to add `ProvideAutoLoad` attribute to class definition:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string)]
public sealed class Command1Package : Package 
...
```

The value of this attribute is a string with Guid identifying UI context, for example context with no solutions opened.

[Source](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2013/MZ2013027.aspx)

Comment: Depending upon what you're trying to do, you could use ProvideAutoload also on SolutionExists, which will load you when the solution loads. That way you're not running on startup just to wait for an event we can tell you about another way.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Have you tried this with the `IVsSolutionEvents2` interface in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop` namespace under 2015?</del>

Disregard, this method is on the interface you are using.

What does your implementation look like?

Here's an example implementation via an abstract class:

```
   [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public abstract class SolutionListener : IVsSolutionEvents, IVsSolutionEvents2, IVsSolutionEvents3, IVsSolutionEvents4, IDisposable
    {
        public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

        public IVsSolution Solution { get; private set; }

        private uint eventsCookie = (uint)ShellConstants.VSCOOKIE_NIL;
        private bool isDisposed;
        private static volatile object Mutex = new object();

        protected SolutionListener(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;

            Solution = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
            Debug.Assert(Solution != null, "Could not get the IVsSolution object");
            if (Solution == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        public abstract int OnAfterCloseSolution(object reserved);
        public abstract int OnAfterClosingChildren(IVsHierarchy hierarchy);
        public abstract int OnAfterLoadProject(IVsHierarchy stubHierarchy, IVsHierarchy realHierarchy);
        public abstract int OnAfterMergeSolution(object pUnkReserved);
        public abstract int OnAfterOpenProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, int added);
        public abstract int OnAfterOpenSolution(object pUnkReserved, int fNewSolution);
        public abstract int OnAfterOpeningChildren(IVsHierarchy hierarchy);
        public abstract int OnBeforeCloseProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, int removed);
        public abstract int OnBeforeCloseSolution(object pUnkReserved);
        public abstract int OnBeforeClosingChildren(IVsHierarchy hierarchy);
        public abstract int OnBeforeOpeningChildren(IVsHierarchy hierarchy);
        public abstract int OnBeforeUnloadProject(IVsHierarchy realHierarchy, IVsHierarchy rtubHierarchy);
        public abstract int OnQueryCloseProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, int removing, ref int cancel);
        public abstract int OnQueryCloseSolution(object pUnkReserved, ref int cancel);
        public abstract int OnQueryUnloadProject(IVsHierarchy pRealHierarchy, ref int cancel);
        public abstract int OnAfterAsynchOpenProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, int added);
        public abstract int OnAfterChangeProjectParent(IVsHierarchy hierarchy);
        public abstract int OnAfterRenameProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy);
        public abstract int OnQueryChangeProjectParent(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, IVsHierarchy newParentHier, ref int cancel);

        public virtual void Initialize()
        {
            if (Solution != null && eventsCookie == (uint)ShellConstants.VSCOOKIE_NIL)
            {
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(Solution.AdviseSolutionEvents(this, out eventsCookie));
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!isDisposed)
            {
                lock (Mutex)
                {
                    if (disposing && Solution != null && eventsCookie != (uint)ShellConstants.VSCOOKIE_NIL)
                    {
                        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(Solution.UnadviseSolutionEvents((uint)eventsCookie));
                        eventsCookie = (uint)ShellConstants.VSCOOKIE_NIL;
                    }
                    isDisposed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I figured out what was wrong with my code.

Comment: Glad you got it working, and yep, delayed loading would do it.  But I am thankful for little things like these to make the overall editor experience better.  I still remember how long it would take to launch VS, or clicking on "Add Reference" and staring at a locked screen for minutes until something showed up.  It's getting better, just have to remember the all the details for things like this.